# Python 3.4 I want to write an intercepting proxy between browser and target application

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I am using python 3.4. I want to write an intercepting Proxy between your browser and the target application. It should log the response into a file which could be analysed at later point of time. I need some guidance to start with or any relevant resources (preferred module with documentation).

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest starting from these resources:

- http://gear11.com/2013/12/python-proxy-server/
- https://github.com/enricobacis/proxapy

But your question is way too broad.